# Implementation of logical shopping cart history

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, angular

I am currently working on html view using angular to display the history of a shopping cart of a user.
The page typically shows a list of operations done by user on his/her cart.

The front-end UI design goes as below:

**19th March 2017:**

07:26 AM - User added 2 item(s) from electronics category and removed 1 item from furniture category.

07:15 AM - User removed 3 item(s) from kitchen category.

**18th March 2017:**

08:00 PM -  User added 3 item(s) from kitchen category.

But the challenge I've here is, the data in DB is stored in rows rather than columns.

First challenge is on how to get data with counts along with operation(added/removed).

Second is on click of above message we need to show the id's of removed/added item(s).

Below are the table(s) along with sample data:

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">TABLE_MASTER</th>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <th>KEY_ID</th>
    <th>KEY_USER_ID</th>
    <th>KEY_CREATED_DATE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>ABCDEF</td>
    <td>19/03/2017:07:26:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>ABCDEF</td>
    <td>19/03/2017:07:15:00:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="6" style="text-align:center;">TABLE_CHILD</th>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <th>KEY_ID</th>
    <th>KEY_CATEGORY_ITEM</th>
    <th>KEY_OPERATION</th>
    <th>KEY_ITEM_ID</th>
    <th>KEY_ORDER_NUM</th>
    <th>KEY_GRP_NUM</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>MOBILE</td>
    <td>ADDED</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>ELECTRONICS</td>
    <td>ADDITIONAL</td>
    <td>545454</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>MOBILE</td>
    <td>ADDED</td>
    <td>135790</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>ELECTRONICS</td>
    <td>ADDITIONAL</td>
    <td>545454</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>CHAIR</td>
    <td>ADDED</td>
    <td>258369</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>FURNITURE</td>
    <td>ADDITIONAL</td>
    <td>656565</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

As I am more a front-end developer, I need someone who can suggest or guide me in right direction towards above problem.
My idea is to get data from pl/sql server as it is and do the business logic at web server(Java/Hibernate) level which will return JSON array list to UI layer.
But I see a complex logic overhead at Business logic layer, so please do share your suggestions on finding a better approach.

Comment: I see HTML tables here, not database tables. Also, "pl/sql" is a programming language, not a DBMS.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Only one database in the world use this language. Could you spell the name?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I may be wrong on pl/sql it is oracle DB I guess..I just created a html template on how the data is stored for reference..